# What does "values that visitors seek the park mean" in this sentence mean?

Tags: meaning, errors

This is from Garett Hardin's essay on the Tragedy Of Commons.

The National Parks present another instance of the working out of the tragedy of the commons. At present, they are open to all, without limit. The parks themselves are limited in extent--there is only one Yosemite Valley--whereas population seems to grow without limit. **The values that visitors seek the parks are steadily eroded.** Plainly, we must soon cease to treat the parks as commons or they will be of no value anyone

Comment: Do you have a link?  This seems to be a typo in that it should read *The values that visitors seek **from/in** the parks are steadily eroded.*

Comment: I looked for another link. It reads  The parks themselves are limited in extent--there is only one Yosemite Valley--whereas population seems to grow without limit. The values that visitors seek in the parks are steadily eroded. Plainly, we must soon cease to treat the parks as commons or they will be of no value to anyone

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [a mistranscription](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22The+values+that+visitors+seek%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) of *The values that visitors seek **in** the parks*

Answer (score 3):

From a quick google search for the original text - http://dieoff.org/page95.htm

The values that visitors seek **in** the parks are steadily eroded.

Whatever source you got this quote from, the "in" was missing.

Comment: Right. That Sorts it. First time on this site. Thanks.

Comment: Perfectly fine. As a bit of advice, if the construct of the sentence doesn't immediately make sense, consider the possibility of a typo first.  They are all too common.

Comment: @Shravani welcome to ELU, please remember to mark the answer that best answers your question as accepted by clicking on the cjheck mark on the left.